# Terraform & Gitlab Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I try to configure Terraform with Gitlab CI/CD, this `.gitlab-ci`:

```
include:
  - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - validate
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
  - cleanup

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: []

build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: prepare

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start

cleanup:
  extends: .terraform:destroy
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: access

variables:
  TF_STATE_NAME: default
  TF_CACHE_KEY: default
```

works without any error in the develop(default, protected) branch, but on other branches for example `feature/test` it gives me this error:

```
$ cd "${TF_ROOT}"
$ gitlab-terraform plan
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
│ 
│ Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
│
```

I put the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` on GitLab variables like this (which I think is enough for my configuration):

[image]

Any idea about the issue and how can I solve it, please?
Is there any additional configuration I should add to my script?

[image]

## Provider

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.54.0"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-remote-state-bucket"
    key    = "terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}
```

and I have a simple resource in the main.tf:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test" {
  bucket = "my-bucket-test-2023-00001"
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell, what is inside that directory? Do you have any kind of backend configuration in your code?

Comment: Is this just that your feature branches don't pass the "protected branches" rule you've used for your AWS creds? IOW untick the "protected" flag for your key and secret in GL and try again.

Comment: Thank you @MattBracewell this solve my issue, you can put your comment as an answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot of your GitLab CICD variables we can see that your AWS creds are "protected" which means they'll only be avaiable for "protected" branches.

You decide which branches are protected so you could mark your feature branches as protected or more simply remove the protection from these two variables.